# Mule - (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) while doing DB insertion

Tags: mule, mule-component

I'm trying to do DB insert to Oracle Database using batch. Everything works fine and insertion works if the number of column is less than 50. But if the number of column is 50 or more I'm getting error (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException).

Full stack trace looks like this:

```
    ********************************************************************************
Message               : 50 (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException).
Payload               : <payload>
Payload Type          : java.util.LinkedHashMap
Element               : /batch-genresourceBatch/process-records/0/0 @ batch-genresource:batch-genresource.xml:29
Element XML           : <db:insert config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
                        <db:parameterized-query><insert query></db:insert>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 50
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaDataParser.computeBasicInfo(OracleParameterMetaDataParser.java:260)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaDataParser.getParameterMetaDataSql(OracleParameterMetaDataParser.java:432)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaData.getParameterMetaData(OracleParameterMetaData.java:58)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData(OraclePreparedStatement.java:11621)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.getParameterMetaData(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1552)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.param.QueryParamTypeResolver.getParameterTypes(QueryParamTypeResolver.java:45)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.param.DefaultParamTypeResolver.getParamTypesUsingMetadata(DefaultParamTypeResolver.java:74)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.param.DefaultParamTypeResolver.getParameterTypes(DefaultParamTypeResolver.java:49)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.AbstractDbConnection.getParamTypes(AbstractDbConnection.java:53)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.query.ParametrizedQueryResolver.getParameterTypes(ParametrizedQueryResolver.java:68)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.query.ParametrizedQueryResolver.resolve(ParametrizedQueryResolver.java:56)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractSingleQueryDbMessageProcessor.executeQuery(AbstractSingleQueryDbMessageProcessor.java:48)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractDbMessageProcessor.process(AbstractDbMessageProcessor.java:81)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.BatchProcessingTemplate.process(BatchProcessingTemplate.java:91)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.DefaultBatchStep.processRecord(DefaultBatchStep.java:360)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.DefaultBatchStep.onRecord(DefaultBatchStep.java:273)
    at com.mulesoft.module.batch.engine.threading.BatchRecordWork.run(BatchRecordWork.java:90)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

In the above log <**payload**>, and <**insert query**> are placeholders which I replaced from original payload and insert query.
As it is client data,I can't share the fields  as such. But The insert query  looks something like this :

```
INSERT INTO Table123(col1,col,.....upto 50)VALUES(#[message.payload.'col1'],#[message.payload.'col2'],...upto #[message.payload.'col50'])
```

Comment: First of all you need to provide your sql query so that we can check,and secondly you have put wrong syntax in db component which is {insert query} and it is wrong. It should be ${insert query} instead

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary As it is client data,I can't share the fields  as such. I've updated the sample insert query.

Comment: Are you sure you have *exactly* 50 columns and values? This error may be caused if you have 50 columns but 51 values for example, such number is error prone. Also try to update your JDBC driver, it may be a bug in the Oracle driver.

Comment: are you using ojdbc7.jar ?